# Wrapping a kernel-driver in userspace: is it real? Is it possible?

Tags: linux-device-driver, interceptor, kernel-module

I have written a Loadable Kernel Module (LKM) which wraps the audio-driver under /dev/snd/pcmC0D0p .

Therefore I moved `pcmC0D0p` to `pcmC0D0p_bak`, renamed my driver to `pcmC0D0p` and passthru every command like `MMAP`, `IOCTL` etc. (but doing other things before forwarding the MMAPed-data).

This is bad, I know (but it's my first step in linux-programing) but it worked.

Today, I read in an [article](http://free-electrons.com/doc/training/linux-kernel/slides.pdf) about `Userspace device drivers`.

Now I'm wondering: should this really be possible? Write a "driver" with userspace-code, implemented methods like MMAP & IOCTL and put it in place of a normal kernel-device (/dev/snd/pcmC0D0p)?

It isn't, isn't it?

IF it's possible, has anyone a simple example, a reference? Anything is really welcome!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to write userspace device drivers, but not quite in the way you're thinking.

An example is the `uio_pci_generic` module, this can be programmed (via /proc) with the ID of a PCI device and will make the device's memory available to you via `mmap`. You can receive interrupts by blocking on a `read` call.

Note how this does not allow you to pretend to be a driver, only to perform driver-like actions (communicating directly with a hardware device, receiving interrupts, etc). No userspace program can ever service a call to ioctl, or expose itself as a character device, without the help of some kernel module.